# What is a nonreductive database?

Tags: bioinformatics, database

A database like Genbank is said to be a nonreductive database. What does that mean ?

Comment: Can you please provide a citation and link to the resource which uses this term? Google doesn't appear to believe that "nonreductive database" is a real phrase.

Comment: @user777 https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/bioinfomethods1%2Flabs%2FCoursera_BioinfoMethods-I_Lab02.pdf Read the first line. There, the nr stands for nonreductive database(As told by the instructor)

Answer (score 0):

If your instructor told you that I think they are wrong.

This link http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=ProgSelectionGuide at Table 2.1 has:

nr Non-redundant GenBank CDS translations + PDB + SwissProt + PIR + PRF, excluding those in env_nr.

suggesting that nr meand Non-redundant, not nonreductive.